# OpenCV how to encode raw image information for imencode?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, memory-management

I am in C++.

Assume some mysterious function `getData()` returns all but only the pixel information of an image.

i.e a `char*` that points to only the pixel information with no metadata (no width, length, height, nor channels of any form)

Thus we have:

`unsigned char *raw_data = getData();`

Then we have another function that returns a structure containing the metadata.

eg:

```
struct Metadata {
    int width;
    int height;
    int channels;
    //other useful fields
}
```

I now need to prepend the object metadata in the correct way to create a valid image buffer.

So instead of `[pixel1, pixel2, pixel3 ...]`

I would have, for example `[width, height, channels, pixel1, pixel2, pixel3...]`

What is the correct order to prepend the metadata and are width, height and channels enough?

Comment: For `cv::imencode`? You don't need to prepend anything anywhere, just [construct a `cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) wrapping the pixel buffer, and pass it to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mat constructor to create an image from data and meta data

> Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t
>   step=AUTO_STEP); // [documentation here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat::Mat(int%20rows,%20int%20cols,%20int%20type,%20void*%20data,%20size_t%20step))

```
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, raw_data);
```

`type` argument specifies the number of channels and data format. For example, typical RGB image data is `unsigned char` and the number of channels is `3` so its type = `CV_8UC3`

Available OpenCV Mat types are defined [cvdef.h](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dcc/cvdef_8h.html)